# How do I create a valid JSON object in rails, without hash rockets or escape quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
  new_set = set.map do |d|
    { id: d.id, first_name: d.firstname, last_name: d.lastname, full_name: d.full_name, score: d.score, photo: d.user.avatar(:medium), sex: d.sex, bio: d.bio, google_plus: d.google_plus, facebook: d.facebook, protocol: d.protocol, verified: d.verified, excellence: d.excellence, verified_at: d.verified_at, excellence_at: d.excellence_at, protocol_at: d.protocol_at, educations: d.educations, qualifications: d.qualifications, services: d.services, branches: d.branches, reviews: d.dispenser_reviews.where(:approved=>true) }
  end
```

Now when I try `new_set.to_json` I get escape quotes.

When I run `new_set.as_json` I get hash rockets.

Is there any way to get valid JSON including the information in `new_set`, above?

Comment: Provide the [raw] output of the two forms. In any case, see http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Comment: The output, with `to_json`, looks correct. Use `puts new_set.to_json`. That is, the extra `\"` are *added* when the value is *displayed* in the REPL, such that it emits a valid string literal. Using `puts` will display the string to stdout and thus won't have this extra (*non-data*) escaping.

Comment: Pretty sure the escaped quotes in there are just showing you that there are quotation marks in the string... there isn't any actual '\' characters in the resulting string. The to_json version is actually valid json from what i see. The only time the "escape quotes is an issue is when you create json with "to_json"... and then stick it in an object and call to_json on that again. The \" all over the place is an artifact of the display in the console (if that's where you are seeing it.

Comment: Wow, using puts solved my issue! I can't believe I missed something so obvious! Can you please provide this as an answer...